# Compare bit-wise operation result to 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I have 3 & operation results in nodejs:

```
> 7&2
2
> 10&2
2
> 15&2
2
```

When I try to compare the result to 0, I get:

```
> 7&2 !== 0
1
> 10&2 !==0
0
> 15&2 !==0
1
```

Why `10&2 !==0` gets 0? I come from C/C++. This is confusing to me. Thanks.

Comment: Amazingly, this surprising precedence order goes all the way back to C (if not B or BCPL).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Nice to know this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parenthesis around the bitwise operation!

```
> (7&2) !== 0
true
> (10&2) !==0
true
> (15&2) !==0
true
```

I'd suggest looking at the official MDN page about [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: This is a fairly well-known duplicate question with plenty of existing answers.

Comment: Sorry, it was my first time seeing this. Also I found it interesting as I used c++ a bit lately, and never thought about the different operator precedence.

Comment: Thank. I'm still failing with operator precedence. I need to work on details more.